# Error when trying to do list compression with new lines Unterminated expression in f-string; missing close brace

Tags: python

```
test2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

print(f'The following Attributes are not supported \n {"\n".join([str(i) for i in test2])}')
```

Intended output:

```
The following Attributes are not supported
1
2
3
4
5
```

Is there any way I could achieve this whilst keeping it on the same line? The error received is as follows: Unterminated expression in f-string; missing close brace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `chr(10)` instead of `'\n'`:

```py
print(f'The following Attributes are not supported \n{chr(10).join([str(i) for i in test2])}')
```